# prevent button from being clicked automatically on page load

Tags: javascript, button, click

When the page is loaded, the button is clicked automatically, but I don't want the function display() to be called until I click the button. How should I fix it?

`<button id="button">Click</button>`

```
window.onload = function () {
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = display();
}
```

I tried
`button.addEventListener("click", display());`but the same problem still occurred.

Answer (score 1):

When you type `display()`, what you're saying to Javascript is, "I'd like to call the display function now, please." So when you type

```
button.addEventListener("click", display());
```

you're similarly saying to Javascript, "I'd like to attach an event listener to the click event ***with the result of the display function***, please." You want to be saying to Javascript, "I'd like you to attach this function `display` to the click event, please. Only call it when the button is clicked." How do we do this in Javascript? Pass the function, but don't call it!

```
button.addEventListener("click", display);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `()` the function will be called, so use raw `display`

`window.onload = function () { var button = document.getElementById("button"); button.onclick = display; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
document.getElementById("").addEventListener("click",function(){
        functionName;
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try preventing the defaults

```js
button.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
e.preventDefaults();
})
```

You can have a further study on how the method works on the following link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp